# Click automatically on Tabs Jquery with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, each, jquery-events

I have html tabs and a continue shopping button. Every tab contains few products. When we land on the page by default first tab is opened. The requirement is this when we click on continue shopping button, user will automatically goes to next tab say tab2, tab3 and then finish i.e. user will have to traverse each tab after clicking on continue shopping button.
Here is my tab code

```
<ul class="tabs-menu">
<li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Warranty</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#tab-2">Accessories</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#tab-3">Software</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="tab-1">
    Content of Tab 1
</div>  

<div class="tab-content" id="tab-2">
    Content of Tab 2
</div>  

<div class="tab-content" id="tab-3">
    Content of Tab 3
</div>  

<a href="#" id="continue-shopping">Continue Shopping</a>
```

Complete code of tabs are here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/us8uc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick demo here it will try to find the next tab, please have a look for more details and as if you need:

`demo` http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/4696/

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks

Comment: One more change, can we turn off traversing as soon as user reach to last tab and change continue shopping button link?

Comment: HI, I am not sure if I understand correctly your idea. But I did a little bit refactor code. So now it will change style of button when user reach the last tab and it won't traverse back to first tab anymore. You can edit in function _reachLastTab() in order to do whatever you want [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/4703/)

Answer (score 0):

use simple setters in your javascript code 
$( ".tab-content" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
for more info check out the api documentation
http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score -1):

Your button can have a click event that does this:

```
$("a[href='#tab-2']").trigger('click');
```

Replace #tab-2 with whatever tab you want to have open by the button

--edit--

Your button logic will look at the tab sequence and just add 1 to the end until there is no more tabs to traverse through. Alternatively, have a "Continue Shopping" button in each of the tab content moving forward